# Bad_CommunicationError (code=0x80050000, description="2147811328, Read timed out") in OPC java code to connect AWS EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, opc

Connecting to **opc.tcp://ec2-.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4840/UAExample** .. SLF4J: Failed to load class

```
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.opcfoundation.ua.common.ServiceResultException: Bad_CommunicationError (code=0x80050000, description="2147811328, Read timed out")
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.tcp.io.TcpConnection.open(TcpConnection.java:730)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.tcp.io.SecureChannelTcp.open(SecureChannelTcp.java:574)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.createSecureChannel(Client.java:644)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.createSecureChannel(Client.java:558)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.createSecureChannel(Client.java:611)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.discoverEndpoints(Client.java:826)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.createSessionChannel(Client.java:369)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.application.Client.createSessionChannel(Client.java:348)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.examples.SampleClient.main(SampleClient.java:156)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:981)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:976)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.utils.bytebuffer.InputStreamReadable._get(InputStreamReadable.java:53)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.utils.bytebuffer.InputStreamReadable.getInt(InputStreamReadable.java:144)
    at org.opcfoundation.ua.transport.tcp.io.TcpConnection.open(TcpConnection.java:645)
    ... 8 more
```

**====================================================**
**Note: **
I am getting the exception whiles connecting AWS EC2 instance.
its works locally on my system server and client systems. when i start the server on AWS Linux system. server jar starts good. but i am unable to connect to client jar from local system. getting bad_communication exceptions.

Comment: make sure that you can access the TCP/IP port of the server from your client